# Join Multiple tables using row value

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables event1,event2,event2 that holds all the users who participated in the event. Each table has nearly million data. These tables keep on increasing with new events.

I have a customer table that holds all the customers of the event

```
Event1
+------+------------+---------+
| id   | phone      | details |
+------+------------+---------+
|    1 | 1234567890 | Detail1 |
|    2 | 2345678901 | Detail2 |
|    3 | 3456789012 | Detail3 |
+------+------------+---------+

Event 2
+------+------------+---------+
| id   | phone      | details |
+------+------------+---------+
|    1 | 1234567890 | Detail1 |
|    2 | 2345678901 | Detail2 |
|    3 | 3456789012 | Detail3 |
+------+------------+---------+

Event 3
+------+------------+---------+
| id   | phone      | details |
+------+------------+---------+
|    1 | 1234567890 | Detail1 |
|    2 | 2345678901 | Detail2 |
|    3 | 3456789012 | Detail3 |
+------+------------+---------+

Customer
+------+------------+--------------+
| id   | phone      | event_name |
+------+------------+--------------+
|    1 | 1234567890 | event1       |
|    2 | 4567890123 | event2       |
|    3 | 7890123456 | event3       |
+------+------------+--------------+
```

To fetch the customer detail i have loop through this query for 3 tables

```
SELECT cu.*,c.* FROM customer cu JOIN event1 c WHERE cu.phone=c.phone


SELECT cu.*,c.* FROM customer cu JOIN event2 c WHERE cu.phone=c.phone


SELECT cu.*,c.* FROM customer cu JOIN event3 c WHERE cu.phone=c.phone
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c8bf/2

How can do this in single Query. I'm saving table names against each customer.

Answer (score 1):

You can join multiple tables

```
    SELECT *
    FROM   customers cu 
       LEFT JOIN event1 e1 
              ON e1.phone = cu.phone 
       LEFT JOIN event2 e2 
              ON e2.phone = cu.phone 
       LEFT JOIN event3 
              ON e3.phone = cu.phone;
```

EDIT:
Left join is used instead of INNER JOIN because a customer can be associated with either event 1 or event 2 or event 3 or not necessarily any of them. The left join then would yield a NULL for values of an event for which the customer is not an associated with thus returning the desired result. For every customer the list events he is associated with and not necessarily being associated with all of them to be returned as a record.

Comment: I'd totally up vote this answer if there was some explanation of why `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Well, OPs question wants to add rows, not columns (he has 3 queries, wants to make them to 1). The difficult part though, is that there is a variable amount of event tables, so you would have to use a procedure to first generate the correct query and then execute it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using cursors to dynamically generate these queries.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_GetAll`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_GetAll`
( 
)
BEGIN
declare done int;
DECLARE table_name      VARCHAR(255) ;  
DECLARE str      VARCHAR(255) ; 

DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR 
select event_name from customer;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
SET  str:='';
SET done = 0 ;
   OPEN cursor_name;
read_loop: LOOP
FETCH cursor_name INTO table_name;

IF done=1 THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
 SET str=CONCAT(str, 'SELECT cu.*,c.* FROM customer cu JOIN ', 
                table_name ,' c on cu.phone=c.phone;');


  END LOOP;
  select str; //this can be changed to direct execution if needed
  CLOSE cursor_name;
END//
```

Execute this sp CALL `SP_GetAll`(); resulting dynamic query would be as follows..

```
SELECT cu.*,c.* FROM customer cu JOIN event1 c on cu.phone=c.phone;SELECT cu.*,c.* FROM customer cu JOIN event2 c on cu.phone=c.phone;SELECT cu.*,c.* FROM customer cu JOIN event3 c on cu.phone=c.phone;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cu.*,c.* FROM customer cu JOIN event1 c WHERE cu.phone=c.phone
UNION
SELECT cu.*,c.* FROM customer cu JOIN event2 c WHERE cu.phone=c.phone
UNION
SELECT cu.*,c.* FROM customer cu JOIN event3 c WHERE cu.phone=c.phone
```

You can combine searchresults of multiple queries by using `UNION`

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c8bf/3)

[Adjusted the answer of Prashant:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38534634/3595565)

As Prashan shows, you can use dynamic sql to build and connect your query-strings. If you then replace the ";" in the resulting strings with " UNION " and directly execute the string you will get your result set (Also you have to use a session variable to be able to execute the query string). [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa77df/1)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_GetAll`()
BEGIN
declare done int;
DECLARE table_name VARCHAR(255) ;  
DECLARE str VARCHAR(1000) ; -- attention: value must be high enough to contain the whole query, so you have to estimate the string length

DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR 
select event_name from customer;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
SET @str='';
SET done = 0 ;
   OPEN cursor_name;
read_loop: LOOP
FETCH cursor_name INTO table_name;

IF done=1 THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
 SET @str=CONCAT(@str, ';SELECT cu.*,c.* FROM customer cu JOIN ', table_name ,' c on cu.phone=c.phone');

  END LOOP;

  SET @str = SUBSTRING(@str, 2);
  SET @str = REPLACE(@str, ";", " UNION ");

  PREPARE QUERY FROM @str;
  EXECUTE QUERY;
  CLOSE cursor_name;
END//
```

Comment: There can be n number of event tabes